# Testing ViewModel with RxSwift

Tags: mvvm, swift2, rx-swift

I am using `ModelView-ViewModel` in the project I am currently working and using `RxSwift`, `RxBlocking` & `RxTests`. Currently I am attempting to test the ViewModel but having many troubles to get my head around this.

So lets say I have an `ExampleViewModel` for my `ExampleViewController`. My `ExampleViewModel` is expecting an `Observable` stream which is the combination (`combineLatest`) of two streams from `UITextField`, one being if the textField is either focused and the other is the stream of text; so something like `Observable<(Bool, String)>`. Depending on whether focused and the context of the string my `ExampleViewModel` will emit an event into its internally exposed property which is an `Observable` the state of the `UITextField`'s backgroundColor; `Observable<UIColor>`.

`ExampleViewModel.swift` :

```
class ExampleViewModel {

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private let _textFieldColor: PublishSubject<UIColor>
var textFieldColor: Observable<UIColor> { get { return self._textFieldColor.asObservable() } }

init(textFieldObservable: Observable<(Bool, String)>) {
    textFieldObservable.subscribeNext { (focus, text) in
        self.validateTextField(focus, text: text)
    }.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}

func validateTextField(focus: Bool, text: String) {
    if !focus && !text.isEmpty {
        self._textFieldColor.onNext(UIColor.whiteColor())
    } else {
        self._textFieldColor.onNext(UIColor.redColor())
    }
}
}
```

(sorry I don't know how to format it correctly)

Basically I would like to test the `ExampleViewModel` class and test that it emits the correct `UIColor` by controlling the focus and text inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of my colleague I found a better way on structuring the `ExampleViewModel` for testability. By separating out the validation method with `ExampleViewModel` and setting the `textFieldColor` `Observable` by using the `map` operator in which the validator is used the validation is done outside and does not use `Rx` simplifying the testing of the logic.

ExampleViewModel

```
class ExampleViewModel {

var textFieldColor: Observable<UIColor>

init(
    textFieldText: Observable<String>,
    textFieldFocus: Observable<Bool>,
    validator: TextFieldValidator
) {
    self. textFieldColor = Observable.combineLatest(textFieldText, textFieldFocus) { ($0, $1) }. map { validator.validate($1, text: $0) }
}
}



 class TextFieldValidator {

func validate(focus: Bool, text: String) -> UIColor {
    if !focus && !text.isEmpty {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        return UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
}
```